# Efficient algorithm for grouping variable-length tuples

Tags: python, algorithm, tuples, grouping

I am trying to devise an efficient algorithm for grouping a sequence of tuples of integers of any length, such as:

```
[(), (1,), (1,1), (1,2), (2,), (2,1,1), (2,1,2), (2,2)]
```

The grouping rule, in Python for example, is the following:

```
def tupleSameGroup(tuple1, tuple2):
    sameGroup = True
    for index in range(min(len(tuple1), len(tuple2))):
        if tuple1[index] != tuple2[index]:
            sameGroup = False

    return sameGroup
```

In rough words, if one tuple is a "subset" of another matching from the beginning, they are the same group. An empty tuple is in the same group as any tuple.

Based on this rule, I want my algorithm to produce as output a list of all unique groups of tuples; so a list of list of tuples, where within the inner list the tuples are all in the same group, but between there is a pair that is not. For the above example, the desired output is:

```
[[(), (1,), (1,1)],
 [(), (1,), (1,2)],
 [(), (2,), (2,1,1)],
 [(), (2,), (2,1,2)],
 [(), (2,), (2,2)]]
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: How efficient is efficient? There is a fairly easy O(n^2) algorithm by building a graph with one node for each tuple and a directed edge between nodes a and b, if tuple a extends to tuple b.

Then run depth first search from ().

Comment: Why isn’t `(2,)` a subgroup of `(1,2)`?

Comment: @rassar, the match needs to be at the same index, for all "shared" indices.

Comment: @ChristianSloper I'd like to do better than O(n^2), but ok if it can't be done. I'm not sure what you mean by "depth first search" - not familiar with graph theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in two steps: First, build a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), or prefix tree, of the tuples:

```
tuples = set([(), (1,), (1,1), (1,2), (2,), (2,1,1), (2,1,2), (2,2)])

tree = {}
for tpl in tuples:
    t = tree
    for x in tpl:
        t = t.setdefault(x, {})
```

In your example, `tree` would be `{1: {1: {}, 2: {}}, 2: {1: {1: {}, 2: {}}, 2: {}}}`

Then, DFS into the tree and add elements to groups whenever the current tuple (the path in the tree) is in the `set` (for faster lookup) of `tuples`. (Leafs in the tree are always valid tuples.)

```
def find_groups(tree, path):
    if len(tree) == 0:
        yield [path]
    for x in tree:
        for res in find_groups(tree[x], path + (x,)):
            yield [path] + res if path in tuples else res
```

This yields:

```
[(), (1,), (1, 1)]
[(), (1,), (1, 2)]
[(), (2,), (2, 1, 1)]
[(), (2,), (2, 1, 2)]
[(), (2,), (2, 2)]
```

Complexity should be O(k), with k being the sum of elements in all the tuples, which is the total number of intermediate- and leaf-nodes in the tree.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful tho a bit hard to understand.

Comment: With no deep analysis, I would be surprised if this is `O(n)` you have both recursion and nested for loops in `find_groups()`.

Comment: @AChampion So? It's easy to see that the number of nodes in the tree is bounded by the total number of elements in the tuples, and the DFS traverses the tree without visiting any node twice, so O(n). If you are _very_ picky you could add the creation of the temporary lists and tuples in `find_groups`, but the _loops_ are no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient solution, but this will produce your desired output and will work with increasing max tuple sizes:

```
s = [(), (1,), (1,1), (1,2), (2,), (2,1,1), (2,1,2), (2,2)]

def tupleSameGroup(tuple1, tuple2, sameGroup=True):

    if any(tuple1[idx]!=tuple2[idx] for idx in range(len(tuple1))):
        return False
    return sameGroup

groups = [[i, j] for i in s for j in [x for x in s if len(x)>len(i)] if tupleSameGroup(i, j)]
```

Yields:

```
[[(), (1,)], [(), (1, 1)], [(), (1, 2)], [(), (2,)], [(), (2, 1, 1)], [(), (2, 1, 2)], [(), (2, 2)], [(1,), (1, 1)], [(1,), (1, 2)], [(2,), (2, 1, 1)], [(2,), (2, 1, 2)], [(2,), (2, 2)]]
```

Then you can combine these groups together based on common elements:

```
combined_groups = [sorted(list(set(i) | set(j))) for i in groups for j in groups if i[-1] in j and i!=j]
```

Yields:

```
[[(), (1,), (1, 1)], [(), (1,), (1, 2)], [(), (1,), (1, 1)], [(), (1,), (1, 2)], [(), (2,), (2, 1, 1)], [(), (2,), (2, 1, 2)], [(), (2,), (2, 2)], [(), (2,), (2, 1, 1)], [(), (2,), (2, 1, 2)], [(), (2,), (2, 2)], [(), (1,), (1, 1)], [(), (1,), (1, 2)], [(), (2,), (2, 1, 1)], [(), (2,), (2, 1, 2)], [(), (2,), (2, 2)]]
```

Finally, we can create a new list without any duplicates:

```
no_duplicates = []
for i in combined_groups:
    if i not in no_duplicates:
        no_duplicates.append(i)
```

Yields:

```
[[(), (1,), (1, 1)],
 [(), (1,), (1, 2)],
 [(), (2,), (2, 1, 1)],
 [(), (2,), (2, 1, 2)],
 [(), (2,), (2, 2)]]
```